# browser.addcommand() using typescript in webdriverIO. unable to get the success

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

As per the webdriveIO documentation i followed the steps in typescript for custom command but no success.

```
my ts.confg
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
      "test/*": [
        "./test/*"
      ]
    },
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true, 
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "out",                          /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es6",                         
    "module": "commonjs",  
"typeRoots": ["./types"],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@wdio/sync",
      "@wdio/jasmine-framework"
   ],                           
    "esModuleInterop": true,                    

  "include": ["./test/**/*.ts","./types/wdio.d.ts","./types/command.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ],
}
```

my types file contains wdio.d.ts file.

```
declare module WebdriverIO {
  interface Element {
    waitAndClick: () => void;

  }
  interface Browser {
    // waitAndClick: (el:WebdriverIO.Element) => void;
    // you can add commands here too
    // waitAndClick: () => void;

  }
}
```

and in wdio.conf.js file

```
before: function (capabilities, specs) {
        browser.addCommand('waitAndClick', ()=> {
            var el = $();
            el.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 5000});
            el.click();
        }, true);
       }
```

and in my spec file

```
 $('mat.classname').waitAndClick();
```

but still Error: selector needs to be typeof `string` or `function`

Answer (score 1):

This error comes form this part of the code:

```
var el = $();
```

You are not passing any selector so the WDIO tells you about this.

The proper way to implement you custom command would be

```
browser.addCommand("waitAndClick", function () {
    this.waitForDisplayed({timeout: 5000})
    this.click()
}, true)
```

Since you gonna call your `waitAndClick` on an element (`$('mat.classname').waitAndClick()`) `this` will refer to the element and you will be able to call you custom command on it.

**Important:**
In this case you can't use arrow function in your custom command since you will not be able to refer to a proper context:

browser.addCommand("waitAndClick", **function () {**